# What's a good way to create subjective views in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view

I'm wondering what's the Rails Way™ to build a "subjective" view, that is, a view who's output is changed based on a provided param.

E.g., consider the following *contrived* case:

A user asks for a `article` in a blog app. In the request, she's sending the param `time_zone=(-)1`, to indicate that her timezone is `-1`. The app should then take that param, and in the output return the article and the time of the creation of that article - converted *to her timezone*.

The rationale for this server-side processing approach, is that it would be easy to change the client view, in particular if one's accessing the rails app through an exposed (mobile) api. (Mind you, it is no problem to handle the before-mentioned case with a client side script etc., but I'd like to avoid that.)

Somehow, I feel that this could easily belong to the `model`, had it not been for the fact that `params` isn't available there. I suppose that is for a reason. `Controller` is, from my point of view, definitely not the place to stick this.

The question is: should I stuff this logic in the `view`?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276001/rails-time-zone-from-url-params)

Comment: Thanks @Slicedpan, I appreciate your help. Unfortunately, I'm not really interested in time zones per se. That is only my example case. It could be anything, really. The question is more 'where' than 'how'.

Comment: writing an answer atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic would probably fit best in a subclass of your controllers. This subclass could define a filter method that sets appropriate instance variables, which you then reference in your view. I linked to a question that does exactly that for your timezone example (albeit without numeric timezone offsets, but the idea is the same). An alternate example might be say a different UI based on a URL parameter. In that case I might do something like this:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_ui
  private
    def set_ui
      if params[:ui] == 'blah'
        @ui = 'blah'
      else
        @ui = 'thing'
      end
      true
    end
end
```

Then in your view you could have something like this:

```
<%= render :partial => @ui %>
```

Then any controllers that you create as subclasses of `ApplicationController` will have this functionality

Comment: Nice! Thanks - I didn't think of it that way. :)